# Ionic Popover button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to make a log out button at the end of the navbar. I made something like this:

[image]

but I want to do like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! post your code so i can help you

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use a simple button and not a pop over. something like this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-button> <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon> </ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>

        <ion-buttons slot="end">
            <ion-item  lines="none">
                         <ion-button> <ion-icon name="logout"></ion-icon> </ion-button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-buttons>

        <ion-title> Title </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: I've created a popover page and in this page I made a button.I just need something to customize this button as i have in mockup.